# bootstrap css fit the background image with the screen

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4, size

```
body {
   -webkit-font-smoothing: none;
     background: url('../img/logo.png') top left;
}
```

Bootstrap-CSS : I would like to create an authentication page and I want to use the image logo.png for the background but I couldn't adapt the image to the screen. For example if I reduce the screen of my window, the picture still have the same size. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: I'm not totally clear what 'the background have the same size' will mean. If the aspect-ratio of of your viewport and of your image differ then you have to decide whether you want to show all the image - in which case there will be margins at either the top/bottom or the sides (background-size: contain) or you want the viewport filled (cover) in which case some of your image will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Like it was already suggested on the comments, you can use the `background-size` property for the.

I have created a small example for you...

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1054218/pexels-photo-1054218.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1> Just a title</h1>
</body>
```

You can read about the [background-size property here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

The `background-size` property sets the size of the element's background image. The image can be left to its natural size, stretched, or constrained to fit the available space.

In my example i have used `background-size: cover` which scales the image (while preserving its ratio) to the smallest possible size to fill the container

Answer (score 0):

SEE "CSS Background Size" on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

background-size(property) will help u

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).